# Is $ ds^2 = g_{11} dx^2 + 2g_{12}dxdy + g_{22}dy^2$ symmetric in the tangent vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, complex-dynamics

It's been a while since I studied differential geometry, so I forgot a lot of basic things. I got therefore stuck at a specific sentence in Milnor's book on complex dynamics.

It says the following:
A Riemannian metric on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ can be described as an expression of the form
$$ ds^2 = g_{11} dx^2 + 2g_{12}dxdy + g_{22}dy^2$$,
where $[g_{jk}]$ is a positive definite matrix, which depends smoothly on the point $z=x +iy$.

I'm confused about the $2g_{12}dxdy$  part. Because, I thought that the Riemannian metric should be  symmetric on the two tangent vectors it gets as input. And if I'm not mistaken, $dxdy$ basically means $dx \otimes dy$ and gets two vectors as input.  But $dx \otimes dy (v,w) \neq dx \otimes dy(w,v)$.

I doubt that it's a mistake from the book, so I'm wondering what I misunderstood.
Thank you.
PS I hope it's not a duplicate (at least it doesn't seem so for me)

Comment: In this context, $dxdy$ has to be understood as $\frac{1}{2}(dx \otimes dy + dy \otimes dx)$ and is indeed symmetric

Comment: I would say that makes for a good answer @Didier

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, $dxdy$ has to be understood as the [symmetric product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor#Symmetric_product) of $dx$ and $dy$, sometimes denoted by $dx\cdot dy$ or $dx \odot dy$, and which is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(dx\otimes dy + dy \otimes dx)$.